# .htaccecss mod_rewrite - Redirect page and alternate

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my `.htaccess` file, I have the entry shown below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about$ /about-us.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

This allows the user to enter `domain.com/about` for the URL, and while **keeping that URL in the address bar**, actually loads `about-us.php` in their browser.

If the user actually types in `domain.com/about-us.php` in the address bar, this loads the correct page in the browser, but I want the address bar to change (or redirect) and actually read `domain.com/about`

How can I prevent a user from reaching the `about-us.php` page directly, and instead make the address bar read `domain.com/about` if they try to reach the page directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule above your existing rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+about-us\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /about [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^about$ /about-us.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Can you please explain your 2nd and 3rd lines? I'll need to apply this rule to several other pages as well

Comment: It uses `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable which represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

Comment: When I apply the rule, I seem to get a "flash" of another page before `domain.com/about` begins to load. Cause..?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by flash here but redirect happens immediately from `/about-us.php` to `/about` with status code as 301.

Comment: I think it was just a glitch. Another question: In the second line, can you please explain `\s/+about-us\.php[\s?]` - Thanks!

Comment: `\s/+about-us\.php[\s?]` is a regex that matches space followed by 1 or more forward slashes followed by `about-us.php` followed by either `?` or a space since `%{THE_REQUEST}` looks like this: `GET /about-us.php HTTP/1.1`

Comment: "..that matches space" - why would there be a space in the url? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes you misunderstood, it is not matching URL it is matching `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable which will have this value **`GET /about-us.php HTTP/1.1`**

Comment: Is it better to match `%{THE_REQUEST}`? Or would it be better to write a RegEx that uses the actual url such as `^about-us(\.php|/)*$` (this one does not work).

Comment: Yes matching `%{THE_REQUEST}` is very much needed here to avoid infinite looping. You cannot match just the URI since your other rule is rewriting `/about` to `/about-us.php`.

Comment: Should I check to make sure it isn't already requesting `/about` to prevent a loop, or does your method ensure a loop is not possible? Something similar to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/about$ [NC]`

Comment: What I provided is fully tested and proven method to prevent looping. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/about$ [NC]` will fail since after rewrite from 2nd rule it will overwrite `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable.

Comment: Two other questions: 1. Why did you remove the `QSA`flag? 2. Why are you using the `NE` flag?

Comment: `QSA` is needed only when you are adding a query parameter and `NE` is not not encoding the resulting URI.

Comment: So if the page will sometimes have query parameters passed, I **should** include the `QSA` flag? And when would you NOT use `NE`?

Comment: Please refer `http://askapache.com` for a very good reference on each of these variables. `QSA` is needed only when you have target like `/about-us.php?foo=bar` in your 2nd rule.